# Google Pagespeed test, image slowing speed

Tags: seo, linux, cache-control, google-pagespeed

I have to test  the speed from my Website with 
PageSpeed Insights, it found what  slow my sites,

[image]

I have to try how [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/79483/google-pagespeed-tells-me-to-leverage-browser-caching-when-caching-is-already-en) to say, but nothing to change...

My Website has with SSL, https://linuxusers.net

I have on my **.htacces**s File add,

```
# BEGIN Expires
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"

ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"

ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"

ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"

ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"

ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"

ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"

ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"

ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"

ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"

ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</ifModule>
# END Expires
```

but nothing change...

Can Please anyone explains me with easy (i am not Web designer..) words how can lose this problem,  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your screen shot has nothing to do with "cache from image short lifetime".
The warning from google is about HTTPS.
You should get an SSL certificate, which [can be free](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) or paid, from your hosting or third party.

When it comes to "cache from image short lifetime", what you could do, in case you have access to .htaccess file (usually placed in root directory) add something like this to it:

### EXPIRES CACHING

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>    
ExpiresActive On    
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"    
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"    
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"    
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"   
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"    
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"    
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"    
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"    
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"    
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"    
</IfModule>
```

### EXPIRES CACHING

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but nothing to change... about the title has you right because I have two problems on my head. The cache problem have on google analytics asked..

Comment: It seems that your score has improved to 98 mobile/100 desktop. Other than that, I am sorry, but I am having trouble understanding what you just said :/

Comment: No problem...because my screenshot image is from lighthouse APP, with Pagespeed speed is as you to say...

Comment: I was looking at Lighthouse as well... will add a screen shot to my answer.

Comment: I am very new these things, but yesterday to reading that lighthouse and pagespeed give a different result... https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/6708